# Wordpress Development Domain

Tags: wordpress, apache2

We are developing Wordpress sites and due to some issues with some plugins once the domain is changed (from dev.domain.com to www.domain.com), we have been using a practice of editing host files in house so that we can develop the site on the www.domain.com domain. 
This solution works fine for us in house, however when a client wishes to see their site in development we have to walk them through the editing of their host files to see the development site and then back so they can see their live site.

Does anyone have a better idea or solution. Is there a way to make this work at the Apache level? Maybe a Chrome app? It needs to be super simple and automated (scripted) if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could create an VPN connection to your "house" so that the fake www.domain.com will be avaible for them.

Comment: Is there a VPN client that is easier to use on the client end other than openvpn? I've used that in the past and it has stumped some mid level techy people.

Comment: I used OpenVPN too, but I always have problems to connect from different devices (like android phone). So I decided to use PPTP server. Is easy to setup, use and compatible with all devices that I'm using.

Comment: so with a PPTP server we would need to setup a DNS server on the VPN which would handle the Development domains correct?

Comment: yes, you just need to point (in PPTP server configuration) your customers to your "internal" DNS server.

Answer (score 0):

So, the issue is that some plugins *think* they're on `www` (or will only behave correctly on `www`)?

Then quite possibly your best quick bet is a Chrome/Firefox extension, although obviously that does require the client to have them installed.

I'd recommend looking at [HostAdmin for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hostadmin/oklkidkfohahankieehkeenbillligdn) and/or [fire-hostadmin](http://code.google.com/p/fire-hostadmin/) for Firefox. These should allow you to amend the hosts without too much hassle or direct editing of protected system files.

It is always worth noting that, depending on the client's computer's security, they may run into potential read-only issues (I believe SpyBot Search & Destroy and similar tools lock the hosts file by default).

Comment: I don't fully understand the issue, but it is something like the plugin use some sort of string length check and if the domain isn't changed in every location for the plugins they stop working and need to be setup again. I hope I have that right. Our WP dev is busy and he gave me the 15 sec explanation. I'm just trying to help them out.


I know HostAdmin has been looked at but I think it might have been deemed to complex for some clients. I'll take a peak at it though.

You are correct read-only issues are a concern here, which is why we'd love an alternate solution

Comment: @Havock Browsing for something completely different, I stumbled across [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7829174/988246), which led me to [Hosts File Editor](http://hostsfileeditor.codeplex.com/); a pretty straightforward open-source tool for doing exactly what you need for your clients. Hopefully this would be easier to use. 

On a perhaps-not-all-that-helpful note: I'd advise regarding those WP plugins with some caution in the future if they're causing you this amount of grief.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at that, quick glance it might just work